# Copy latest file from FTP

Tags: puppet

I need to use an Ftp location where latest packages are dumped, then get the latest file and copy it over to node using Puppet. 
Would like to know the best way to do this in node.pp file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about ftp, but an example of http location could work like this using puppet's package resource,

```
package { 
    "package name" :
      ensure => "latest",
      source => "http://url",
      provider => "rpm",
}
```